# lighthouse + localhost geth - why "sync can take longer when using remote eth1 nodes"?

Tags: go-ethereum, lighthouse

I have geth alongside lighthouse on the same computer. I'm running lighthouse with `--eth1-endpoints http://localhost:8545`.

However this appears in my ligthouse logs: `sync can take longer when using remote eth1 nodes`

What am I missing? is it just a default message?

```
Jul 10 10:56:01.001 WARN Syncing eth1 block cache                est_blocks_remaining: 3101, msg: sync can take longer when using remote eth1 nodes, service: slot_notifier
Jul 10 10:56:13.001 INFO Syncing                                 est_time: 2 days 1 hrs, speed: 9.33 slots/sec, distance: 1662564 slots (32 weeks 6 days), peers: 35, service: slot_notifier
Jul 10 10:56:13.001 WARN Syncing eth1 block cache                est_blocks_remaining: 2561, msg: sync can take longer when using remote eth1 nodes, service: slot_notifier
Jul 10 10:56:25.000 INFO Syncing                                 est_time: 2 days 9 hrs, speed: 8.00 slots/sec, distance: 1662501 slots (32 weeks 6 days), peers: 35, service: slot_notifier
Jul 10 10:56:25.001 WARN Syncing eth1 block cache                est_blocks_remaining: 1838, msg: sync can take longer when using remote eth1 nodes, service: slot_notifier
Jul 10 10:56:37.006 INFO Syncing                                 est_time: 2 days 9 hrs, speed: 8.00 slots/sec, distance: 1662374 slots (32 weeks 6 days), peers: 34, service: slot_notifier
Jul 10 10:56:37.006 WARN Syncing eth1 block cache                est_blocks_remaining: 1055, msg: sync can take longer when using remote eth1 nodes, service: slot_notifier
Jul 10 10:56:49.001 INFO Syncing                                 est_time: 2 days 21 hrs, speed: 6.69 slots/sec, distance: 1662311 slots (32 weeks 6 days), peers: 35, service: slot_notifier
Jul 10 10:56:49.001 WARN Syncing eth1 block cache                est_blocks_remaining: 311, msg: sync can take longer when using remote eth1 nodes, service: slot_notifier
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a default message which now has been removed
https://github.com/sigp/lighthouse/issues/2452